# Duplicate numpy array rows where the number of duplications varies

Tags: python, numpy

Whereas there is a numpy array for which one desires to duplicate each value a specified number of times:

```
np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

and a second array definining the number of duplications desired for each corresponding index position in the original array:

```
np.array([3,3,2,2])
```

How does one produce:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

Obviously, it is possible to use iteration to produce the new array, but I'm curious if there is a more elegant numpy-based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> numpy.repeat([1,2,3,4], [3,3,2,2])
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```